# Running SpecFlow Scenario Outlines from Test Plans in Azure DevOps (VSTS)

Tags: azure-devops, specflow

I'm using SpecFlow scenario outlines to generate multiple tests based off a single test case in Azure DevOps. Then I am using azure devops release pipeline to deploy the tests and run them using an automated test plan.

The problem I am having is a SpecFlow Scenario Outline represents 1 test case in Azure DevOps, but I can only link 1 of the 4 generated Test Explorer tests to a test case via "Associate to Test Case" to Azure DevOps. When I deploy the pipeline it only runs the single test that is associated, not every test in the Scenario Outline. How can I get it to run all the tests in Scenario Outline?

**Example:**

I can only right click on *AddingUserInformationScenarioOutline("1",null)* and link that specific test to VSTS, I cannot link the higher grouping *AddingUserInformationScenarioOutline(4)*. Running the test plan will result in just test *AddingUserInformationScenarioOutline("1",null)* being run.

[image: SpecFlow Scenario and Scenario Outline]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot associate more than one test method with a test case, but you can associate a test method with more than one test case. Please see [Associate your test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=vsts#associate-your-test) for details.

So, in your scenario you can create multiple test cases and associate each test method with them...

Another way is configuring your build process to execute tests using **SpecFlow+ Runner**:

> **SpecFlow+ runner**
>
> Smarter integration test runner for SpecFlow
>
> SpecFlow+ Runner is a dedicated **test execution engine** providing better
>   reporting, faster (parallel) test execution and better VS/TFS
>   integration

Highly recommend  to use specflow+ runner to run specflow tests via TFS/Azure DevOps (VSTS).

To configure your build process to execute tests using SpecFlow+ Runner:

1. Open TFS/VSTS and switch to your build definition.
2. Click on **Add build step** to add a new step to the build definition.
   Click on **Test** in the list of categories and click on **Add** next to
   "Visual Studio Test".
3. Configure the build step as follows:

   Enter the path to your **Test Assembly**

   If you are using both MSTest and SpecFlow+ Runner, enter
   the path to NuGet package folder in the **Path to Custom Test Adapters**
   field. If you do not enter the path here, only your MSTest tests
   will be executed as TFS cannot find the SpecFlow+Runner test
   adapter.

   Enter the name of your .srprofile file in the **Run Settings File**
   field if the name is not `TFS.srprofile` or `default.srprofile` (see
   above).
4. Save your changes.

More details please refer this tutorial: [SpecFlow+ And Build Servers](http://specflow.org/plus/documentation/SpecFlowPlus-and-Build-Servers/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will likely use the solution of creating additional test cases in Azure DevOps and linking each one to a generated test method. My end goal is to be able to manage which automated tests get run and with what configuration through Azure DevOps Test Manager, not just run all automated each time, and I think that solution fits with my end goal.